# Measuring Area of Pixels "Connectivity "

Tags: general-topology, geometry, connectedness

Suppose you have a binary image (ones and zeros). Is there a one number metric that measures the "connectivity" of the shape present in the image?

For example, consider images **A**, **B** and **C**, where green is pixel value 1 and white pixel value 0.

[image: 3 images]

Is there a metric that says:

- **A** is very connected;
- **B** is less connected than A;
- **C** is less connected than B;

I don't know if the term connectivity is correct here, but is the best way I found to express this idea. Also, please help with the tags, I am not sure which ones to use.

Comment: I get the feeling that what you're asking for is the number of "connected components" of the space.

Comment: Perhaps, can you please elaborate?

Comment: You can read the Wikipedia page to get an idea if you're unfamiliar with the concept: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space. The connected components are in some sense the maximal disjoint pieces which constitute the whole space. For example, the set $[0,1] \cup [4,5]$ has two connected components, namely $[0,1]$ and $[4,5]$. In the example in your question, it appears that $A$ has one connected component, $B$ has $2$ or $3$ depending on how you wish to define connectedness here, and $C$ has $5$ or $6$. I hope this helps a bit.

Comment: @Miguel It's the number of parts the shape consists of. The A has only one connected component, B has two (considering the three pixels at the lower-right to be connected) and C has 5 components...

Comment: Thanks, I also found the concept of "genus" (number of holes) and [Digital Topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_topology) but calculating it for these images gives unreasonable results. For instance, calculating for figure **A** gives 1.5 holes...

Answer (score 1):

*From the comments above.*

---

I get the feeling that what you're asking for is the number of "connected components" of the space. You can read the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space) to get an idea if you're unfamiliar with the concept. The connected components are in some sense the maximal disjoint pieces which constitute the whole space. For example, the set $[0,1] \cup [4,5]$ has two connected components, namely $[0,1]$ and $[4,5]$. In the example in your question, it appears that **A** has one connected component, **B** has $2$ or $3$ depending on how you wish to define connectedness here, and **C** has $5$ or $6$. I hope this helps a bit.